# read and write doesn't work in named pipes c++

Tags: c++, named-pipes

Please excuse my English, its not the best. Thank you.

I am suppose to write 2 simple programs, which are suppose to enable two communication between processes in/with named pipes(C++).

Each code search through the directory and (name of the directory is suppose to be inputed by a user) search for FIFO file type. After finding a file, first code opens to read, second code opens to write. If process can't find a file, then it will ask user to input a new path.

First code write the message in the terminal(stdin) and send it through the pipe to second process. Second process read the message from the pipe and shows it in terminal(stdout). Both processes are suppose to end after reading message from stdin and sending a statement 'END';

I am still learning and trying to find more about named pipes so for now I could only write some basics programs(just to read and write) but still I don't understand why both of them doesn't work.

Can You tell me what is wrong with my codes? Thank You.

here is my code for read

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
char sentence [256];
int fp, numr ,numop;

    umask(0);
    
    fp = mkfifo("myfifo", S_IFIFO|0666);
    if(fp < 0)
    {
        printf("Cant make a file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    numop = open("myfifo",O_RDONLY);
    if(numop < 0)
    {
        printf("Cant open the file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    numr = read(fp,&sentence,sizeof(sentence));
    if( numr < 0)
    {
         printf("Cant read the message\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fgets(sentence,256,stdin);
    
    printf("Message: %s\n",sentence);
    close(fp);
    
    return 0; 

}
```

here is for write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd , numw;
    char sentence [256];

    fd = open("myfifo", O_WRONLY);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        printf("Can't open a file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf ("Enter the message : ");
    fgets(sentence,250,stdin);

    numw = write(fd,sentence,strlen(sentence)+1);
    if(numw < 0)
    {
        printf("Can write the message");
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0; 
}
```

can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: No `#incluide` directives, for starters.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik when I run write programs it shows that I can enter the message but when I try to run second program then nothing happens

Comment: I advise you to read this [tutorial](https://peter.bloomfield.online/introduction-to-win32-named-pipes-cpp/) about names pipes in C++

Comment: Are you familiar with the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming? The one that says "your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do"? Can you explain, in your own words, what your second program tells your computer to do? No, it doesn't tell your computer to read from the named pipe and show the message. The program also tells your computer to do something else, too, and that's what your computer is waiting to do.

Comment: Shouldn't this post be tagged as C instead of C++ (and edited changing C++ for C)?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).